# Logger slf4j - Как задать уровень логирования при запуске?

Tags: java, slf4j

Всем привет!

Я в spring-app.xml задал бин лога:

```
<bean id="logger" scope="prototype" class="org.slf4j.LoggerFactory" factory-method="getLogger">
        <constructor-arg name="name" value="log"/>
</bean>
```

Дальше, я расставил в классах нужные мне уровни логгирования для различных ситуаций:

```
@Autowired
private Logger log;

log.warn(...);
log.info(...);
log.debug(...);
```

У меня есть текстовый файл config.conf, который я подгружаю в программу при запуске:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(configFile));
```

Как сделать, чтоб уровень логирования (info, debug), скажем для консоли, я мог указать в файле config.conf?

Comment: это настраиватся в configFile. приложите к вопросу ваш configFile

Comment: Я не понял, про какой configFile идет речь? Мой config.conf содержит параметры, необходимые мне в программе, а больше конфигов у меня нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для логирования можно использовать специальный конфигурационный файл log4j.properties и расположить его в `src/main/resources/log4j.properties`.

Теперь можно настраивать логирование и его уровень по-разному:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
 
# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Также можно задавать фильтры для уровня логирования:

```
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.a.LevelMin=DEBUG
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.a.LevelMax=INFO
```

тогда для консоли будут логированы только DEBUG и INFO уровни, но общий уровень задается в первой строчке `log4j.rootLogger=INFO`. Если вам нужны уровни ниже, то просто укажите другой.

Comment: У меня логгер создается бином в spring-app.xml

И видимо из-за этого он не видит настроек src/main/resources/log4j.properties

Как ему указать настройки?

Comment: Разобрался, не хватало зависимостей в помнике. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: всегда пожалуйста. вы можете благодарить, приняв ответ как верный, если, конечно, ответ решил вашу проблему